# How do I get my Trivia Answers to stay with my Questions in an random array?

Tags: java, arrays, oop

I'm making a multiple choice trivia game and I have my questions in an array that randomizes each time you boot or answer a question. I'm not sure how I get would my multiple choice answers to pop up with the correlated questions while they're in an array and have them randomly assigned to the JButtons?

I have the JButton placeholders made and the questions in an array that is working and randomizing everytime I load a new question, but I'm not sure how to approach keeping the answers with every random question in an array.

Random array question genertor

```
import java.util.Random;

public class QuestionArray {

    private static String[][] questions = new String[30][4];

    // fill 2D array with questions
    public static void fillArray() {

        // Kindergarten math
        questions[0][0] = "9 - 2 =";
        questions[1][0] = "6 + 3 =";
        questions[2][0] = "4 + 4 =";
        questions[3][0] = "2 + 7 =";
        questions[4][0] = "5 + 4 =";

        // Kindergarten science
        questions[0][1] = "What sound does a dog make?";
        questions[1][1] = "What do caterpillars become?";
        questions[2][1] = "What color is the grass?";
        questions[3][1] = "What animal goes \"Bwak!\"?";
        questions[4][1] = "All birds have which body part?";

        // Kindergarten history
        questions[0][2] = "In what state do you live?";
        questions[1][2] = "What colors make up the American flag?";
        questions[2][2] = "What type of animal is the bald eagle?";
        questions[3][2] = "How many red stripes are on the American flag?";
        questions[4][2] = "How many white stripes are on the American flag?";

        // Kindergarten English
        questions[0][3] = "Which color is spelt right?";
        questions[1][3] = "Which animal is spelt right?";
        questions[2][3] = "Select the missing letter. B_rd";
        questions[3][3] = "Select the missing number. 1 2 _ 4 5";
        questions[4][3] = "A T-Rex is a:";

        // 1st grade math
        questions[5][0] = "Is 3 an odd or even number?";
        questions[6][0] = "Which number is larger, 8 or 2?";
        questions[7][0] = "Which numbers are missing? 21 22 23 _ 25 26 _";
        questions[8][0] = "2 + ? = 5";
        questions[9][0] = "9 - 6 = ";

        // 1st grade science
        questions[5][1] = "Which is a vegetable?";
        questions[6][1] = "If it is snowing, is it hot or cold outside?";
        questions[7][1] = "How many fingers and toes do you have in total?";
        questions[8][1] = "How many legs do spiders have?";
        questions[9][1] = "Which animal lives in the sea?";

        // 1st grade history
        questions[5][2] = "How many states are in America?";
        questions[6][2] = "How many stars are on the American flag?";
        questions[7][2] = "At school, you sing the Pledge of _____?";
        questions[8][2] = "What is a mayor?";
        questions[9][2] = "Who was the 1st American President?";

        // 1st grade English
        questions[5][3] = "What are vowels?";
        questions[6][3] = "How many consonats does the word \"sunflower\" have?";
        questions[7][3] = "What is the correct spelling?";
        questions[8][3] = "Which is spelt correctly?";
        questions[9][3] = "What are the 5 W's?";

        // 2nd grade math
        questions[10][0] = "98 - 54 =";
        questions[11][0] = "121 + 157 =";
        questions[12][0] = "The Zoo has 6 rhinos and 9 wolves. How many animals are there?";
        questions[13][0] = "Will has 2 quarters and 7 pennies. How much money does Will have?";
        questions[14][0] = "73 - 21 = ";

        // 2nd grade science
        questions[10][1] = "What do plants need to grow?";
        questions[11][1] = "How many planets are in our solar system?";
        questions[12][1] = "How many layers make up the Earth?";
        questions[13][1] = "What part of the water cycle is rain?";
        questions[14][1] = "A warm-blooded vertebrate with fur is a ___?";

        // 2nd grade history
        questions[10][2] = "Who delivered the \"I have a dream\" speech?";
        questions[11][2] = "What are the four cardinal directions?";
        questions[12][2] = "What are the three branches of government?";
        questions[13][2] = "In which country were the famous pyraminds built?";
        questions[14][2] = "In which city is the Statue of Liberty?";

        // 2nd grade English
        questions[10][3] = "What punctuation is needed for this sentence? \"Who am I\"";
        questions[11][3] = "Which is spelt correctly?";
        questions[12][3] = "Similes use ___.";
        questions[13][3] = "Complete the sentence: \"Ava felt sick ___ lunch.\"";
        questions[14][3] = "Choose the adverb: \"The girl waited patiently.\"";

        // 3rd grade math
        questions[15][0] = "How many sides does a hexagon have?";
        questions[16][0] = "11 x 0 =";
        questions[17][0] = "10 x 4 =";
        questions[18][0] = "A lion eats 5 steaks daily. How many steaks does it eat in 4 days?";
        questions[19][0] = "778 - 291 =";

        // 3rd grade science
        questions[15][1] = "On which planet do we live?";
        questions[16][1] = "What mineral can be found in pennies?";
        questions[17][1] = "Which planet is known for its large ring that circles it?";
        questions[18][1] = "Which animal does NOT have a vertebra? ";
        questions[19][1] = "Which is of the following is NOT an insect?";

        // 3rd grade history
        questions[15][2] = "Who was the President during the Civil War? ";
        questions[16][2] = "Who is on the $5 bill?";
        questions[17][2] = "What is the capitol of Virginia?";
        questions[18][2] = "Who is the second president of the United States of America?";
        questions[19][2] = "Which northern state is by itself and connected to Canada?";

        // 3rd grade English
        questions[15][3] = "What is the plural form of cactus?";
        questions[16][3] = "Apply the appropriate pronoun: Jennifer told me that ___ had to go.";
        questions[17][3] = "Apply the appropriate pronoun: The kids asked ___  parents to join.";
        questions[18][3] = "Homophones: The dog wanted to play outside ___.";
        questions[19][3] = "Homophones: ___ 3rd graders just like you!";

        // 4th grade math
        questions[20][0] = "3/7 + 1/7 =";
        questions[21][0] = "9/3 =";
        questions[22][0] = "10 x 10 =";
        questions[23][0] = "99/9 =";
        questions[24][0] = "Ned has 3 bananas and 3 apples. What fraction of the fruit is bananas?";

        // 4th grade science
        questions[20][1] = "How many moons does Earth have?";
        questions[21][1] = "Which organism is lowest on the food chain?";
        questions[22][1] = "What keeps us on the ground and keeps us from floating into the sky?";
        questions[23][1] = "What is Magma?";
        questions[24][1] = "Which planet is the 7th away from the sun?";

        // 4th grade history
        questions[20][2] = "How many seas are there";
        questions[21][2] = "Who led slaves to freedom via the Underground Railroad?";
        questions[22][2] = "Which two countries were part of the Space Race?";
        questions[23][2] = "How many continents are there?";
        questions[24][2] = "What year did man set foot on the moon for the first time in history?";

        // 4th grade English
        questions[20][3] = "What is the suffix of the word \"Rapidly\"?";
        questions[21][3] = "What is the root word of the word \"Beautiful\"?";
        questions[22][3] = "Place the comma: Mom started cutting up carrots, celery and peppers.";
        questions[23][3] = "Select the best word: ___ umbrella is useful for when it rains.";
        questions[24][3] = "Select the best word: Mom waited for more than ___ hour in traffic.";

        // 5th grade math
        questions[25][0] = "11 x 23 =";
        questions[26][0] = "10 x 17 =";
        questions[27][0] = "239 x 53 =";
        questions[28][0] = "Improper Fraction: 11/5";
        questions[29][0] = "Gary needs 1 1/3 cups of milk for 1 meal. How many cups for 3 meals?";

        // 5th grade science
        questions[25][1] = "What is the term for when a liquid changes into gas?";
        questions[26][1] = "What do rings in a tree’s trunk say about the tree?";
        questions[27][1] = "How many moons does Mars have?";
        questions[28][1] = "What are the 4 soil types?";
        questions[29][1] = "Which has the highest rating on the hardness scale?";

        // 5th grade history
        questions[25][2] = "What was the first US state?";
        questions[26][2] = "How long was the United States in World War 2?";
        questions[27][2] = "What was World War I originally called?";
        questions[28][2] = "What happened at the Boston Massacre?";
        questions[29][2] = "Which African American leader helped lead the boycott of city buses?";

        // 5th grade English
        questions[25][3] = "Select the subject of the following sentence: \"I saw an albino crocodile!\"";
        questions[26][3] = "Select the predicate of the following sentence: \"The cats meow.\"";
        questions[27][3] = "Select the prepositional phrase: \"Before class, Josh asked for a pen.\"";
        questions[28][3] = "Where does the comma belong? \"Last winter school got canceled twice.\"";
        questions[29][3] = "Select the conjunctions: \"I like cooking and eating, but not doing dishes.\"";
    }

    // return question based on grade and topic
    public static String getQuestArray(String grade, String topic) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int row = 0;
        int col = 0;

        if ( grade == "K" && topic == "math")
        {
            row = rand.nextInt(5);
            col = 0;
        }
        else if ( grade == "K" && topic == "science")
        {
            row = rand.nextInt(5);
            col = 1;
        }
        else if ( grade == "K" && topic == "history")
        {
            row = rand.nextInt(5);
            col = 2;
        }
        else if ( grade == "K" && topic == "english")
        {
            row = rand.nextInt(5);
            col = 3;
        }
        else if ( grade == "1" && topic == "math")
        {
            row = rand.nextInt(5) + 5;
            col = 0;
        }
        else if ( grade == "1" && topic == "science")
        {
            row = rand.nextInt(5) + 5;
            col = 1;
        }
        else if ( grade == "1" && topic == "history")
        {
            row = rand.nextInt(5) + 5;
            col = 2;
        }
        else if ( grade == "1" && topic == "english")
        {
            row = rand.nextInt(5) + 5;
            col = 3;
        }
        else if ( grade == "2" && topic == "math")
        {
            row = rand.nextInt(5) + 10;
            col = 0;
        }
        else if ( grade == "2" && topic == "science")
        {
            row = rand.nextInt(5) + 10;
            col = 1;
        }
        else if ( grade == "2" && topic == "history")
        {
            row = rand.nextInt(5) + 10;
            col = 2;
        }
        else if ( grade == "2" && topic == "english")
        {
            row = rand.nextInt(5) + 10;
            col = 3;
        }
        else if ( grade == "3" && topic == "math")
        {
            row = rand.nextInt(5) + 15;
            col = 0;
        }
        else if ( grade == "3" && topic == "science")
        {
            row = rand.nextInt(5) + 15;
            col = 1;
        }
        else if ( grade == "3" && topic == "history")
        {
            row = rand.nextInt(5) + 15;
            col = 2;
        }
        else if ( grade == "3" && topic == "english")
        {
            row = rand.nextInt(5) + 15;
            col = 3;
        }
        else if ( grade == "4" && topic == "math")
        {
            row = rand.nextInt(5) + 20;
            col = 0;
        }
        else if ( grade == "4" && topic == "science")
        {
            row = rand.nextInt(5) + 20;
            col = 1;
        }
        else if ( grade == "4" && topic == "history")
        {
            row = rand.nextInt(5) + 20;
            col = 2;
        }
        else if ( grade == "4" && topic == "english")
        {
            row = rand.nextInt(5) + 20;
            col = 3;
        }
        else if ( grade == "5" && topic == "math")
        {
            row = rand.nextInt(5) + 25;
            col = 0;
        }
        else if ( grade == "5" && topic == "science")
        {
            row = rand.nextInt(5) + 25;
            col = 1;
        }
        else if ( grade == "5" && topic == "history")
        {
            row = rand.nextInt(5) + 25;
            col = 2;
        }
        else if ( grade == "5" && topic == "english")
        {
            row = rand.nextInt(5) + 25;
            col = 3;
        }

        String questPass = questions[row][col];

        return questPass;

    }

}
```

Answer JButtons

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Question extends JFrame {

    private JFrame frmQuestion;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String grade, String topic) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Question window = new Question(grade, topic);
                    window.frmQuestion.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     * @param topic 
     * @param grade 
     * @param questions 
     */
    public Question(String grade, String topic) {
        initialize(grade, topic);
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     * @param topic 
     * @param grade 
     */
    private void initialize(String grade, String topic) {
        String questPassed = QuestionArray.getQuestArray(grade, topic);

        frmQuestion = new JFrame();
        frmQuestion.setTitle("Trivia");
        frmQuestion.setBounds(200, 200, 450, 300);
        frmQuestion.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frmQuestion.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblQuestionHere = new JLabel(questPassed, SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblQuestionHere.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12));
        lblQuestionHere.setBounds(10, 42, 412, 27);
        frmQuestion.getContentPane().add(lblQuestionHere);

        JButton btnAnswer = new JButton("Answer 1");
        btnAnswer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Answer.main(null);
                frmQuestion.dispose();
            }
        });
        btnAnswer.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12));
        btnAnswer.setBounds(53, 80, 147, 75);
        frmQuestion.getContentPane().add(btnAnswer);

        JButton btnAnswer_1 = new JButton("Answer 2");
        btnAnswer_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                Answer.main(null);
                frmQuestion.dispose();
            }
        });
        btnAnswer_1.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12));
        btnAnswer_1.setBounds(233, 80, 147, 75);
        frmQuestion.getContentPane().add(btnAnswer_1);

        JButton btnAnswer_2 = new JButton("Answer 3");
        btnAnswer_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Answer.main(null);
                frmQuestion.dispose();
            }
        });
        btnAnswer_2.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12));
        btnAnswer_2.setBounds(53, 175, 147, 75);
        frmQuestion.getContentPane().add(btnAnswer_2);

        JButton btnAnswer_3 = new JButton("Answer 4");
        btnAnswer_3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Answer.main(null);
                frmQuestion.dispose();
            }
        });
        btnAnswer_3.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12));
        btnAnswer_3.setBounds(233, 175, 147, 75);
        frmQuestion.getContentPane().add(btnAnswer_3);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        menuBar.setBounds(0, 0, 434, 23);
        frmQuestion.getContentPane().add(menuBar);

        JMenu menu = new JMenu("File");
        menuBar.add(menu);

        JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem("Main Menu");
        menuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Launcher.main(null);
                frmQuestion.dispose();
            }
        });
        menu.add(menuItem);

        JMenuItem menuItem_1 = new JMenuItem("Quit");
        menuItem_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frmQuestion.dispose();
            }
        });
        menu.add(menuItem_1);

        JMenu menu_1 = new JMenu("Help");
        menuBar.add(menu_1);

        JMenuItem menuItem_2 = new JMenuItem("How to Play");
        menuItem_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                HowToPlay howTo = new HowToPlay();
                howTo.setLocation( 250, 150 );
                howTo.setSize( 450, 300 );
                howTo.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        menu_1.add(menuItem_2);
    }
}
```

Trivia game asks random questions from an array based on Grade and Subject then answers assigned to JButtons tell correct or incorrect.

Comment: Side note, see: [How do I compare Strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Create a class called `Question` that contains the question as `String` and a list or whatever of answers.